# Blackberry Connection Nightmare

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, http, blackberry

I'm busy writing a Program that Transmits GPS Coordinates to a Server from a mobile phone where the coordinates are then used for calculations. But I'm constantly hitting a wall with blackberry. I have built the Android App and it works great but can't seem to contact the server on a real blackberry device. I have tested the application in a simulator and it works perfectly but when I install it on a real phone I get no request the phone.

I have read quite a bit about the secret strings to append at the end of the url so I adapted some demo code to get me the first available transport but still nothing ...

The **Application is Signed** and I normally then either install it by debugging through eclipse or directly on the device from the .jad file and allow the application the required permissions.

The current code was adapted from the HTTP Connection Demo in the Blackberry SDK.

Could you have a look and give me some direction. I'm losing too much hair here ...

The Backend Service that keeps running:

```
public void run() {

        System.out.println("Starting Loop");

        Criteria cr = new Criteria();
        cr.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        cr.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        cr.setCostAllowed(false);
        cr.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        cr.setPreferredResponseTime(1000);
        LocationProvider lp = null;
        try {
            lp = LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);
        } catch (LocationException e) {
            System.out.println("*****************Exception" + e);
        }
        if (lp == null) {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Dialog.alert("GPS not supported!");
                    return;
                }
            });
        } else {

            System.out
                    .println(lp.getState() + "-" + LocationProvider.AVAILABLE);

            switch (lp.getState()) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                // System.out.println("Provider is AVAILABLE");
                while (true) {
                    Location l = null;
                    int timeout = 120;
                    try {
                        l = lp.getLocation(timeout);
                        final Location fi = l;

                        System.out.println("Got a Coordinate "
                                + l.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()
                                + ", "
                                + l.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude());

                        System.out.println("http://" + Constants.website_base
                                + "/apis/location?device_uid=" + Constants.uid
                                + "&lat="
                                + l.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()
                                + "&lng="
                                + l.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude());

                        if (!_connectionThread.isStarted()) {
                            fetchPage("http://"
                                    + Constants.website_base
                                    + "/apis/location?device_uid="
                                    + Constants.uid
                                    + "&lat="
                                    + l.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()
                                    + "&lng="
                                    + l.getQualifiedCoordinates()
                                            .getLongitude());
                        } else {
                            createNewFetch("http://"
                                    + Constants.website_base
                                    + "/apis/location?device_uid="
                                    + Constants.uid
                                    + "&lat="
                                    + l.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()
                                    + "&lng="
                                    + l.getQualifiedCoordinates()
                                            .getLongitude());
                        }

                        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60);

                    } catch (LocationException e) {
                        System.out.println("Location timeout");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("InterruptedException"
                                + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

My Connection is Made with:

```
ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
ConnectionDescriptor connDesc = connFact.getConnection(getUrl());

// Open the connection and extract the data.
try {
    // StreamConnection s = null;
    // s = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(getUrl());
    HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();
    /* Data is Read here with a Input Stream */
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: You don't have to append anything if you are using the OS 5.0 or higher, just use ConnectionFactory.

Comment: I am using ConnectionFactory ? Am I using it wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in connections? Are they timing out? Or maybe the GPS is timing out (expect 1 minute or so in BB).

Comment: Have debug with the phone (6.x) and it prints the coordinates and the url that that I want it to call but nothing. No error, no message and when I check the server no request ... I'm quite lost.

Comment: What do you receive as HTTP response? error code? exception?

Comment: Hi will finally have some time do debug this weekend. Will Report back with the HTTP response and any errors I get during execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Using a function I found online to determine which ; extension to use when connecting by using numerous Try / Catch. Then had to set the Internet APN settings. I'm in South-Africa using Vodacom so the APN is "Internet" with no Password.

Barely have hair left ....

Comment: Is the BlackBerry your testing on provisioned with a BlackBerry data plan? If not, that could be the cause of your difficulties.

Comment: Not that I know of. As I understand it by using APN I will be using the airtime of device? Or will I be going through the internet blackberry provides. Would love to not cost the user anything extra but I'm still a bit confused on this issue. Any Help ?

Comment: BlackBerry OS provides a large number of methods of connecting to networks that are suitable for different purposes. In later OS APIs much of the complexity has been abstracted away, but that abstraction assumes the device has been properly provisioned. Using a direct TCP connection (the APN) is not necessarily the least expensive option for your customer. Have a look at this link for a description of all connection options: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Network-Transports/ta-p/446834